# Sending email on exchange server using log4net

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server, log4net

Hi I have used the following credentials for sending mail on SMTP server

```
  <log4net>
    <!--
  This writes the log information to the console window.  It only logs events
  that are at least at the INFO level (which would mean that DEBUG events are not captured.
  -->
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <!--
  This stores information in the mylogfile.txt file.  It only captures log events
  that contain the key word test or error.
  -->
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="null" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <!--<staticLogFileName value="true"/>-->
      <!--<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>-->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level | %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt} |  %5rms | %-22.22c{1} | %-method | %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LogSmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <to value="abc@xyz.com" />
      <from value="from@xyx.com" />
      <!--<smtpHost value="1.16.4.2" />-->
      <username value="abc@xyx.com" />
      <password value="pass@123" />
      <subject type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="subject" />
      <port value="25" />
      <bufferSize value="0" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR" />
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level | %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt} | %5rms | %-22.22c{1} | %method | %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
```

This works fine on POP/IMAP server. But now my email client is on Microsoft exchange with the following credentials

http://s23.postimg.org/vi8emm1q3/mail.jpg
(snapshot of the exchange mail credentials)

But it does not work on the exchange credentials. Can someone tell me what I am missing here.

Thanks,
Preeti

Comment: You need to enable SMTP on Exchange and connect to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the anti-virus was blocking the port. I perhaps need to connect with the IT admin peeps to get this sorted. Once I disable the antivirus the emailer works.